# How can I pinch zoom an embed pdf in ios?

Tags: ios, object, pdf, embed, pinchzoom

I have an app which it shows pdf documents. I've tried using iframes and objects to show the pdf, but I can't zoom in/out with touch gestures (pinch zoom).

I also used the [pdf viewer from Google](https://docs.google.com/viewer) but I still can't zoom it using touch gestures.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom), it works amazing. And, I used img tags to display the pdf documents.